# Keeping the fractions in \frac the same in inline math

Tags: fractions

Is there a way to change the way `\frac` behaves in inline math such as `\[*code*\]`? It keeps changing it to `\dfrac` which I don't want. It works for `\(*code*\)` but I want it centered and auto line skip and I don't want to do it manually. I don't want to manually change the text size, instead a general case that changes it for good.

[image]

Looks out of place in my opinion.

Comment: `\tfrac` (from amsmath) or `\textstyle\frac` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, much simpler than I thought. Now I feel unintelligent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to extend the version in the comments. Of course you can use `\tfrac`, but if you want to keep `\frac` you can switch between math styles with `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` as shown below:

[image: fracs]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
    This is text in LaTeX with some math \(P\left( -\frac{25}{19},\frac{40}{19} \right) = \frac{-25+80}{19}\) inline.
    The same in displaystyle: \[\left( -\frac{25}{19},\frac{40}{19}\right) = \frac{-25+80}{19}\]
    Now we imitate displaystyle in text: \(\displaystyle  P\left( -\frac{25}{19},\frac{40}{19} \right) = \frac{-25+80}{19}\) And of course some textstyle in displaystyle: \[\textstyle\left( -\frac{25}{19},\frac{40}{19}\right) = \frac{-25+80}{19}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately, `\displaystyle` fractions in text make the baselines very uneven, and the resulting page tends to look like it has a skin disease.  best to delay the style decision until you've looked at the output.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree with you that is not always advantageous to the style, but I just wanted to show the different options.